# Trying to showing data in a select with method pluck - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to do a simple select summoning data from method pluck.

I tried to do dd($var) in the controller and the x380 data entries are receiving correctly.

Then the next error appears:

> Undefined variable: valor (View: C:\laragon\www\envio-curriculum\resources\views\enviar_curriculum.blade.php)
>
> $valor is undefined
> Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $valor }} with {{ $valor ?? '' }}

If I do this I can see the blade without errors, but in the select appears x380 void data put what I put in the option section.

What am I missing?

##### `EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\Configuracion;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost;


class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        $configuraciones = Configuracion::pluck('ID', 'variable', 'valor', 'valor_numerico', 'tabla', 'texto_largo', 'observacion');

        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum(), 'configuraciones' => $configuraciones]);
    }

    public function store(StoreEnviarCurriculumPost $request)
    {
        EnviarCurriculum::create($request->validated());

        return back()->with('status', '¡Curriculum creado con éxito!');
    }
}
```

##### `Configuracion.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Configuracion extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'configuracion';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    protected $fillable = [
        'variable',
        'valor',
        'valor_numerico',
        'tabla',
        'texto_largo',
        'observacion'
    ];
}
```

##### `enviar_curriculum.blade.php`

```html
<select name="titulacion" id="titulacion">
    <option disabled selected value="">* Titulación mas reciente</option>
    @foreach ($configuraciones as $configuracion)
          <option> {{ $valor }}</option>
    @endforeach   
</select>
```

Comment: If i understand this right, $valor is an array inside the configuraciones array? please check if you can print $configuraciones['valor'] !?

Comment: True, I can't dd($configuraciones['valor']), the error says `Undefined index: valor`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed passing `$configuracion` in your loop.

Try this:

**In your controller**

```
$configuraciones = Configuracion::select(['ID', 'variable', 'valor', 'valor_numerico', 'tabla', 'texto_largo', 'observacion'])->get();
```

**OR**

```
$configuraciones = Configuracion::get(['ID', 'variable', 'valor', 'valor_numerico', 'tabla', 'texto_largo', 'observacion']);
```

```html
<select name="titulacion" id="titulacion">
    <option disabled selected value="">* Titulación mas reciente</option>
    @foreach ($configuraciones as $configuracion)
        <option>{{ $configuracion['valor'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Now it's telling me `Trying to access array offset on value of type int (View: C:\laragon\www\envio-curriculum\resources\views\enviar_curriculum.blade.php)`

Comment: try `{{ $configuracion->valor ?? 0 }}` @ElcondeLucanor

Comment: Now it appears x380 options, but all of them are 0 hehehe. It's an advance.